# PLL placing fails on Lattice 5LP1K

Tags: fpga, pll, synthesis, lattice

I have a board with a Lattice ICE40 5LP1K FPGA that does some small jobs like handling communication protocol and some IOs.
My problem is that I cannot compile the project as the IceCube tells me

```
I2709: Tool unable to complete IOPlacement for the design
E2694: PLL: pll_inst.pll_pll_inst could not be placed
E2693: PLL placement is infeasible for the design
```

I'm using a PLL of type `SB_PLL40_2F_CORE`

Now if I free up the global buffer G0 `PIOT_46B` (exclude it from the pin assignment file) everything works fine.
So I assume the PLL requires a global buffer to be placed, but I'm using pin `PIOT_46B` as a normal LVCMOS IO, does this also occupy the global buffer?
My Clock is on `PIOB_3b`.

Freeing up any other global buffer pin doesn't solve my problem, it has to be this specific one as it seems.

I further found some information that it would may help to use `SB_PLL40_2F_PAD` instead of `_CORE` but that's only supported for clock inputs on bank0 or 2 but mine is placed on bank3.

Is there any solution/explanation for this issue or do I have to change my board routing to be able to free up `PIOT_46B`?

**Edit** It appears that only inputs are not supported, if I define `PIOT_46B` to be an output the design can be synthesized. But so far I don't understand the phenomenon.

Comment: I'd look at the routing map if the lattice software generates one, odds are your running out of some global resource like a wire because there  are too many signals using global resources and it's trying to route the PLL signal on the global wires that are connected to all the blocks.

Comment: It generates a placer output file but I don't know if that contains any useful information regarding my issue. What I figured out according to [PLL User Guide](http://www.latticesemi.com%2F-%2Fmedia%2FLatticeSemi%2FDocuments%2FApplicationNotes%2FIK%2FiCE40sysCLOCKPLLDesignandUsageGuide.ashx%3Fdocument_id%3D47778&usg=AOvVaw373MsDuxFvG62p5Ijv9u8x) is that it works if `PIOT_46b` is used as an output.I just don't understand what all my GBs are used up for...

Comment: Here's the correct document link [PLL User Guide](http://www.latticesemi.com/view_document?document_id=47778)

Comment: Someone ever faced the same issue? If I know there's nothing I can do about it I at least know that I have to change my PCB.

Answer (score 1):

I remember that I had some trouble with the PLL instantiation (SB_PLL40_CORE) for a ICE40UL1K-CM36A. IIRC it was the combination of "which input and output to use". In my case the solution was to avoid PLLOUTCORE and use PLLOUTGLOBAL instead. I think I let the tool decide where to place the clock and locked that pin (F2) later.

So my recommendation: check if different combination of CORE vs GLOBAL make any difference if this does not help let the tool decide where to place the clkin pin. Maybe you are lucky and there is another pin which is not G6 and the tool is fine with.

Answer (score 1):

I just ran into this today and found that the problem was that I assigned pin A6 (on the C132 package of ICE40HX8K) named IOT_198_**GBIN0** to an input.  If I changed that pin to an output (or used a different non-global input) then the problem of not being able to place the PLL went away.  I use the GLOBAL output of the PLL since this is the main clock for my tiny example.

Kind of a bummer that the tool does not offer an easy solution to the problem (or solve the problem itself).  I use none of the other 8 global pins except GBIN5 which is being used as the clock input.  There are two PLLs in this device so if that pin is really tied to a particular PLL, it seems that the other PLL could have been used without me knowing what is going on.  Maybe that is not possible since the PLL is tied to a particular global input.  I learn something new every day with this device and tools.

The most painful thing I learned about global resources was that I needed to add this **syn_global_buffers** magic after my top level module to get the design to place.  For example:

```
module Gpu(
     input  Clk
    ,input  nRst
    ,output[7:0] Led
    ,input UsbRx    
    ,output UsbTx
    ,output[7:0] Debug
)    /* synthesis syn_global_buffers = 4 */ ;
```

Comment: As it’s currently written, your answer is unclear. Please [edit] to add additional details that will help others understand how this addresses the question asked. You can find more information on how to write good answers [in the help center](/help/how-to-answer).